# Odoo Calendar Printing

Tags: fullcalendar, odoo

I need to print pdf reports of meetings from the calendar view in Odoo. One solution that I found was to have a print button in the calendar view like in list view, open a wizard on clicking it, and have the user to select the date range for the meetings report. But this is kind of redundant as the user would have already selected a date range in the calendar view. What I want to know is whether there is any way that the date selection in the calendar view can be used to print the reports?